# Manipulate DSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I have the following EDO:

```
f'[t] == (1/V*a/T) - ((Lambda + Q/V)*f[t])
```

Taking into account that the variables V,a,T,Lambda and V are constant, I would like to make a "Manipulate" with the result f[t] of solving the EDO, depending on the value of the variable Q, taking into account that t goes from 10 to 1800 and Q can take values between 0.123 and 12.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["`*"];
sol = DSolve[f'[t] == (1/V*a/T) - ((Lambda + Q/V)*f[t]), f[t], t, 
    GeneratedParameters -> c] /. {V -> 1, a -> 1, T -> 1, Lambda -> 1,
     c[1] -> 0};
f[t] /. sol
Manipulate[Plot[%, {t, 10, 1800}], {Q, .123, 12.3}]
```